# How to include SELECT statement into INSERT INTO with concatenation & pdo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I've recently started to code the shopping cart class and its repository(functions) and I had a problem with SELECT statement inside INSERT INTO statement and the problem is when I try to execute this code It executed but "SELECT statement always returning 0 in database " informed that productPrice is exist in database with its values

the code:

```
class ShoppingCartRepo
{

    public function addToCart($productId, $cartId)
    {
        $dbh = mySqlDatabase::getConnectionObject();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO cartitem (productId, cartId, singlePrice, quantity)
                      VALUES (:productId, :cartId, 'SELECT productPrice FROM products WHERE productId = :productId', 1)";

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $data = array(
            ':productId' => $productId,
            ':cartId' => $cartId,
        );
        $stmt->execute($data);
        return $dbh->lastInsertId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you quote the select statement?

Comment: I dunno :P what the hell happened to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use quotes, what you want is called subquery:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cartitem (productId, cartId, singlePrice, quantity)
                  VALUES (:productId, :cartId, (SELECT productPrice FROM products WHERE productId = :productId), 1)";
```

Comment: how do I know that this product in this cart 
I mean that when user clicks on add to cart it will added then the value of <input> will change from add to cart to remove from cart
how this would happen ??